# Sybase SQL + PHP, why Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: php, sql, sybase

```
//$type has value of "Hello+World"
$type = $_POST['series'];

$sql = "select max(id) from TABLE_NAME where type = " . $type;

$result = sybase_query ($sql, $db_ro_conn) or die(db_error("query failed $sql"));
$row = sybase_fetch_row($result)
```

I get the error "incorrect syntax near "=". y15, procedure N/A in the $sql line.

What are the possible reasons why this is happening?  Somehow it doesn't work.  Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: `$type` is null or empty string or contains some special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Put quotes around your $type like this:

```
$type = $_POST['series'];

$sql = "select max(id) from TABLE_NAME where type = '" . $type. "'";

$result = sybase_query ($sql, $db_ro_conn) or die(db_error("query failed $sql"));
$row = sybase_fetch_row($result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me start with this. ALWAYS escape POST/GET values in your query!

The error is probably caused by $type is string and not quoted. Try changing $sql to

```
$sql = "select max(id) from TABLE_NAME where type = '" . $type."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not quoting the value:

```
$type = str_replace("'", "''", $_POST['series']);
$sql = "select max(id) from TABLE_NAME where type = '" . $type . "'";
```